# how big companies using react JS manage their platform SEO?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I hope you are well.
I am a junior in the world of SPAs with react. and one question bothers me.
Knowing that react JS is not SEO friendly, how do big companies (Facebook, Discord, Uber Eats ...) make their platforms SEO friendly?

Does it code two applications:
A website via a programming language that does server-side rendering (PHP, Ruby, Python...) and puts a url to an admin page coded in react js express js, or does it proceed in another way?

This will help me in a small personal project, thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably by paid adds and popular demand. 
There is alot of blog posts about SEO and react 
https://proxify.io/articles/react-seo#how-do-you-set-up-server-side-rendering

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.